Firebase Firestore in Xcode frameworks - getting a lot of errors
How do I get Firebase Firestore to work ok as a dependency in an Xcode framework / module?
I'm splitting up a monolithic xcode project into frameworks to make it easy to create app extensions and other targets. Sadly, I'm running into some framework dependency issues with Firebase, Xcode and SwiftPM.
My current Xcode structure is as follows
App

Embeds and Signs imports Infrastructure
Linked to various Firebase libraries

Infrastructure Framework

Links (Do Not Embed) to Networking and Core
Links to FirebaseFirestore framework for @DocumentID in various response objects to decode into

Networking Framework

Links (Do Not Embed) to Core
Has very generic Database + HTTP service classes
Links to FirebaseFirestore for database querying

Core Framework

Shared utility classes

Before refactoring the application built ok, but now I get 103 errors from the FirebaseFirestore Framework with a linking note
   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm using SwiftPM to handle dependencies, and can share a test project to demonstrate the architecture, if anyone would like it. I'm using the latest SDK, but other versions also fail.

Set the FIREBASE_SOURCE_FIRESTORE environment variable when opening Xcode to use the source distribution of Firestore.
The binary version is statically linked and won't work with multiple clients.
See https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#cloud-firestore_14
